# If statement never executes

Tags: c, debugging, if-statement, optimization

I have [this](https://github.com/LordCreepity/SDM) simulator located in the file `main.c`. Using the assembler located in `asm.c`, I can generate a program image that *should* be an infinite loop:

```
stoa 0xFF
jin 0x0
```

However, when I examine the simulator under a debugger, it passes over the if-statement completely; the test is never executed and the code goes straight to `break;`. The if-statement in question:

```
case '\x80':
    if (acc >= 128) {
        lIByte = arg;
        rIByte = arg + 1;
        jumped = 1;
    }
    break;
```

Maybe this is an optimization issue?

Comment: What is the `switch` statement's control expression (including the types of any variables involved).  Are you sure that case is what's being selected?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Here is the entire file: [main.c](https://github.com/LordCreepity/SDM/blob/master/main.c)

Comment: acc is of type char, it will never be greater than 128, my guess is that your compiler removed this if as it will never be executed.

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick A `char`. This instruction is supposed to jump only if `acc` is negative.

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick It is not an `unsigned char`, it is a regular `char`. Its maximum should be 255.

Comment: You may want to use `unsigned char` instead of `char` in your program if you want a range of 0..255. The range of a `char` will be -128..127 if your compiler treats it as signed.

Comment: @LordCreepity unsigned char is always in the range 0-255, char may be signed meaning its range is -128 to 127

Comment: @LordCreepity: on many platforms (most that I have dealt with) `char` is a signed type.  So you are likely running into the problem that Ryan and Mark have commented about.

Comment: Oh, wait... I seems to have gotten signed and unsigned confused. Heh. Sorry about that.

Comment: regarding this line: `memory = calloc(1, 4096);` when calling `calloc()` (or malloc or realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: `memoryImage = open(argv[1], 0);`  do not access any command line parameter beyond argv[0] with out first checking argc to assure that parameter was actually entered by the user.

Comment: regarding this line: `read(memoryImage, memory, 4096);`  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful